# receiving function pointers and storing them in variables in standard c

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I would like to have a function called "get_example_by_id" which takes in an `int l`  and "returns" `int a, b` and two function pointers `f` and `J`. My initial take would be:

```c
int a, b;
double (*f) (double), (*J) (double, double);
get_example_by_id(l, &a, &b, &f, &J);
```

Later on, I need `f` and `J` to be callable, since I need to them to make calculations.
Right now, when I try to call

```c
double f1(double t);
double F1(double t, double alpha);

void get_example_by_id(int l, int *a, int *b, double (*f) (double), double (*F) (double, double)) {
    
    switch(l) {
        case 1:
            *a = 0; *b = 5; f = f1; F = F1;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


double f1(double t) {
    return t;
}

double F1(double t, double alpha) {
    return 1/tgamma(alpha + 2) * powl(t, alpha + 2);
}
```

(get_example_by_id is defined above in not here shown section) f(1) is NULL and therefore not callable. Additionally I get this error "undefined Symbol _f and _F" since experimenting which I don't know how to resolve. Any help is appreciated even new ideas about how to code this.

P.S. there are more functions to come and this is supposed to become some kind of database

EDIT: Working example would be `printf("%f", f(1))` after `get_example_by_id()` call, so that I can be sure the function call is actually performed right.

EDIT2: fixed actually function pointer declaration. Problem is now (as before) `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` when executing where `f = NULL`

Comment: With `double *f (double);` you have a forward declaration of a function named `f` that returns a pointer to a `double` and takes one single `double` argument. If you want to declare a pointer to a function you need to do `double (*f) (double);`

Comment: Also, you never actually call any of your functions, directly or through a function pointer. Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Perhaps dereference f and F as you are doing with *a and *b?  Also, &f1 and &F1.  So `*a = 0; *b = 5; *f = &f1; *F = &F1;`

Comment: I also highly recommend you use some descriptive names for your functions and variables. `f`, `F`, `f1`, `F1`? That's very confusing.

Comment: `double (*f) (double)` was the mistake for my minor problem here, thanks. Well, a simple `printf("%f", f(1))` is sufficient for a working example. I will update my question. And the functions are getting more descriptive names if things actually work out.

Comment: You need to take pointer to pointer to function to modify the pointer itself. See in my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a function pointer. To declare function pointers you need to use different syntax.

```
double (*f)(double), (*J)(double, double);
```

To modify the pointer you need to pass reference to it:

```
double f1(double t);
double F1(double t, double alpha);

void get_example_by_id(int l, int *a, int *b, double (**f) (double), double (**F) (double, double)) {
    
    switch(l) {
        case 1:
            *a = 0; *b = 5; *f = f1; *F = F1;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


double f1(double t) {
    printf("It is f1\n");
    return 1.1;
}

double F1(double t, double alpha) {
    printf("It is F1\n");
    return 0.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double (*f)(double), (*J)(double, double);
    get_example_by_id(1, &(int){0}, &(int){0}, &f, &J);
    f(0.);
    J(0.,0.);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oTndWeze9

Comment: if code above is executed with this fix it will say `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` where `f` is `NULL`

Comment: @Max you cant dereference NULL pointers. Read the second part of the answer